# How to use Create React App version 4.0.3 instead of 5.0.0

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, create-react-app

I'm approaching an issue with create-react-app. Their newest release requires Node 14 but at my work latest approved version is 12.16.3.

In this case I am wondering how can I use create-react-app with older version of node. I have tried to install older version globally like this:

```
npm uninstall -g create-react-app
npm install -g create-react-app@4.0.3
npx create-react-app my-app --scripts-version 4.0.3
```

but I'm still getting

```
You are running Node 12.16.3.
Create React App requires Node 14 or higher.
Please update your version of Node.
```

Comment: please download and update your node version

Comment: You can use nvm to manage your node versions

Comment: Unfortunately there is no way for update or getting nvm due to the policy of software at my company

Comment: Then you can't create a react app. because at least need Node 14 or higher to create a react app

Answer (score 0):

Download the latest version of nodejs becouse i don't know any other way to handle older versions

Than in 'cmd' >npm uninstall -g create-react-app
Than.. >npm install -g create-react-app@latest